# Problem specific android question regarding frame by frame animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to perform frame by frame animation in android. For this task I created an xml file called "anim.xml" like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false"> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/square0" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/square1" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/square2" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/square3" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/square4" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/square5" android:duration="100" />
    </animation-list>
```

Then at a frame layout that I have defined, I tried to set it as background and start it at onCreate like this:

```
    FrameLayout imgView = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1);
    imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim);
    AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) imgView.getBackground();
    anim.start();
```

What I'm experiencing is the first frame only, but what I'm going for is an animation of squares to be on a loop. Do you have any opinions regarding what I have done wrong ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experience issues before when trying to get animations to start in the onCreate method. Try repalcing your last line with something like:

```
imgView.post(new Runnable()
    {       
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            anim.start();
        }
    });
```

This will essentialy make you animation start after onCreate has executed.

Answer (score 4):

To me, Matt's solution seems a little overpowered for this case. You can simply move your call of the `start()` method to the `onWindowFocusChanged()` method because at that point the `AnimationDrawable` is fully attached to the window and can actually be started. Like this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    anim.start();
}
```

Do all the other stuff in your `onCreate()` method and make the `AnimationDrawable` a class variable, so you can access it from `onWindowFocusChanged()` method.